# How do I find elements that already have been printed and skip them from printing again?

Tags: java, arrays, adt, repeat, bag

The method in question is below. This method is supposed to take a string and return the frequency of an item using bag adt. I have it working, however if I (for example) enter "test", it will show the outputs T, S, and T with their respective(and albeit, correct) frequencies. However, I'd like the output to just be T, S with their frequencies.

```
    public int getFrequency(String str){
        int index=0;
        char[] nArray = new char[sArray.length];

        for(int i=0;i<sArray.length; i++){
            char a = sArray[i];
            String s = Character.toString(a);
            index = consonants.getFrequencyOf(s);
            if(index != 0 && consonants.contains(s)==true){
                for(int x=0;x<nArray.length;x++){
                    if(nArray[i] == sArray[x]){
                        continue;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print(s + ": ");
                        System.out.println(index);
                        nArray[i] = sArray[i];
                        break;
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: Where are `x`, `sArray` and `consonants` declared?

Comment: The function does not make a lot of sense. You never actually use `str`, which I suspect is translated into `sArray` somewhere else. The value for `index` that you return is only appropriate for the very last character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use a `HashMap`, to store the Characters with their correspondin frequency: -

```
public Map<Character, Integer> getFrequency(String str){

    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    Map<Character, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<str.length(); i++) {

        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        // If character is a not consonant.. continue with next iteration

        if (vowels.contains(ch)) {
            continue;
        }

        Integer val = freqMap.get(ch);

        if (val != null) {
            // Put new entry in Map.. With character and count = 1

        } else {
            // Increment val by 1, and update the map for this character
        }

    }
    return freqMap;
}
```

**Just a confirmation about your code: -**

```
index = consonants.getFrequencyOf(s);
if(index != 0 && consonants.contains(s)==true){
```

The 2nd condition looks Vague to me.. Because if `index !=0`, then it means that `consonants` contains `s`.. Then why check again??

Or, your `getFrequencyOf(s)` is doing something else than checking the containment, that we can't see??

Comment: Note: I had this program working without problem utilizing hashmaps, arraylists, and arrays. However, I need to utilize the Bag ADT (consonants variable in my code)

Comment: @steverngallo.. Then check for consonants before adding to HashMap.. Don't add them..

Comment: There is no need to write `new Character(a)`. That's the job of autoboxing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. Can't unbox to int. If `freqMap.get(a)`
gives null.. It will throw NullPointerException..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the else-block. You will get it in any case. But you need to get it only when the cycle ends. You should rewrite internal cycle like this:

```
                public int getFrequency(String str){
                    char[] sArray = str.toCharArray();
                    char[] nArray = new char[sArray.length];
                    int[] fArray = new int[sArray.length];

                    for(int i=0; i < sArray.length; i++){
                        char a = sArray[i];
                        String s = Character.toString(a);

                        if(consonants.contains(s)==true){        

                            for(int x=0; x <= i; x++){
                                if(nArray[x] == sArray[i]){
                                    fArray[x]++;

                                    break;
                                }

                                if (x == i){
                                    nArray[i] = sArray[i];
                                    fArray[i] = 1;
                                }       
                            }                
                        }
                    }        

                    for (int k = 0; k < fArray.length; ++k){
                       if (nArray[k] == 0){
                           continue;
                       }

                       System.out.println(String.valueOf(sArray[k]) + ": " + String.valueOf(fArray[k]));
                    }

                    return fArray[fArray.length - 1];
                }
```

Comment: Yes, there was an error (her 'fArray[fArray.length - 1]'). I fix a bug and update code.